# How to build this QUERY getting the latest entry based on a time stamp?

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

So I am trying to get the latest entry based on a column containing the timestamp, but I'm not getting my head around getting that entry without necessarily selecting that column.

[G Sheets Sample data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Qj6GXpRU435SjXJiMoS-D7LlsrRmMg9sMMip_9vXk1g/edit?usp=sharing)

Appreciate your help very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B5:B&C5:C&D5:D; 
 SORT({'From this sheet'!G2:G&'From this sheet'!H2:H&'From this sheet'!I2:I\'From this sheet'!Q2:Q}; 
 ROW('From this sheet'!Q2:Q); 0); 2; 0 )))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C5:C&D5:D; 
 FILTER({'From this sheet'!H2:H&'From this sheet'!I2:I\'From this sheet'!Q2:Q}; 
 'From this sheet'!R2:R="Finalizado"); 2; 0 )))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I appreciate your response. Sorry I didn't mention it but it has to be via QUERY, because I'm actually pulling the real data from another file, using ```QUERY(IMPORTRANGE(...``` ...and (being an idiot) I had pointed the wrong rows as the expected result.

Comment: @santosOnit can you post your query formula?

Comment: Something like: ```=QUERY(
IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/zzzxxxxxxxxxxxx/edit";"Produção!A1:R"); 
"select Col6, Col1, Col7, Col8, Col9, Col10, Col13, Col15, Col11, Col12
where Col2 = 'Corte' and Col18 = 'Finalizado' or Col2='Costura' and Col15 > 0 ";1)```

Comment: So, do I wrap the one above into the one you suggested?